# Map class in Dynamics AX is pass by reference or pass by value

Tags: dictionary, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Map class in Dynamics AX 2012 is pass by reference or pass by value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All arguments in AX calls are passed by value. Beware that if you pass a record buffer (or map buffer), it is the *reference* that is passed by value but any field updates will update the buffer directly.

It is possible to call a .Net method by reference using the [byref keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc586700.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jan. Nice precised answer. Appreciated!